# chef-solo fails with 'lpadmin: Unable to connect to server: Transport endpoint is not connected'

Tags: linux, cups

I'm having trouble finding the root cause of this chef-solo run failing. It was working ok. I'm thinking maybe a cups update or something may be causing it, but I'm not sure.

`Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
        ------------------------------------
        Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
        ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20171122-12850-1c8t7wf" ----
        STDOUT:
        STDERR: lpstat: Invalid destination name in list "Packing_Station_002_DOC".
        lpadmin: Unable to connect to server: Transport endpoint is not connected`

If I run the command it's failing on, the command itself works, but it fails in the chef run...

`$ lpstat -p Packing_Station_002_DOC -l
printer Packing_Station_002_DOC is idle.  enabled since Mon 31 Jul 2017 02:10:00 PM BST`

Info:
chef-solo version: Chef: 12.19.36

CUPS version: cups-1.6.3-29.el7.x86_64

```
Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/opt/chef-solo/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/runner.rb:41:in `run_action'

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/chef-solo/cookbooks/manhattan/recipes/add_printer.rb

 14:     bash "add printer if it doesnt exist" do
 15:         code <<-EOH
 16:         if [[ ! $(lpstat -p #{printer['name']} -l) ]]; then
 17:         lpadmin -p #{printer['name']} -E -v socket://#{printer['ip']};
 18:         fi
 19:         EOH
 20:
 21:         user 'root'
 22:     end
 23:
```

The list of printers is read from a json file, and has been working previously.

`"wms": {
        "printers": [
          {
            "name": "Packing_Station_002_DOC",
            "ip": "10.41.6.10"
          },
          {
            "name": "Add new name here",
            "ip": "Add new ip here"
          }
        ]`

I have localhost listening in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf

Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock

Listen *:631

Listen 127.0.0.1:631

Answer (score 0):

The message "Transport endpoint is not connected" indicates that lpadmin cannot talk to the CUPS service. Here are the steps I would use to troubleshoot this:

- Make sure that the CUPS service is running. In your case, that's not the issue, since the command works from the command line.
- Verify that chef-solo is running as root.
- Check that SELinux allows connections to the CUPS server. To confirm, perform your chef run with setenforce 0 (not on a production machine, of course).
- Make sure that the service is listening on TCP ports 631. Confirm that it is actually listening with the netstat -ltnp command, not just by looking at the configuration file. Also confirm that there is not an old cups process occuping these ports.
- Check that the firewall is not blocking port 631. An unlikely cause for localhost, but better safe than sorry. If this is not a production machine, simply turn off the firewall temporarily for testing.

Source/inspiration: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1435563 (subscription required).